# Is there a way to add hover effects to the plank?

Tags: plank

Can I add hover effects to the plank? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Here is the tutorial:

https://eos-techs.com/2020/06/05/howto-add-zoom-effect-on-plank/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by hover effects, but I recently found out Plank has a “secret“ menu, just **Crtl right click** on it and pick Preferences, you can change its theme, position, add docklets etc.